# Problem in UIButton in iPhone programming

Tags: iphone, uibutton

Can you give me some links or example programs to create UIButtons on a view and on action on it, we need to create one more button on other view.. 
plz help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-(void)action:(id)sender
{

}


UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];  
button.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 30];

[button setTitle:@"TITLE"
        forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[button addTarget:self
        action:@selector(action:) 
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.view addSubview:button];
```